# Upgrade xampp to latest and php 7.1 but php its still php 5.6 in my computer

Tags: php, xampp, upgrade, php-7.1

I'm updating xampp to the latest version and php-5.6 to php-7.1. When I run `PHP -v` in xampp it's showing me php-7.1.14, but when I run this command at the Windows command prompt it still shows me php-5.6.30.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location for your new xampp folder should be in the C:/ directory when installing. if one already exists, rename the old xampp folder to something else like xampp-old, then proceed with the new installation. Always works for me.